# JMeter Critical Section Controller dead lock

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, deadlock

About [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller):

> The Critical Section Controller ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a named lock will be taken before executing children of controller.

It's not that hard to create a dead lock and make JMeter stuck
If inside lock A add lock B and inside other lock B add lock A with a few threads there's a dead lock: 
[image]

Can this be avoided ? and if not can there be a warning for users using this controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed using, the way you show it can lead to Java Dead Lock as it's the equivalent of a "synchronized" block in Java.

As JMeter provides a kind of algorithmic way to develop a test, this looks regular to me.

You can potentially raise an enhancement request for detection of Dead lock or provide a PR improving documentation.

I think project will be happy to merge it.

Comment: How to provide a PR improving documentation? send to user@jmeter.apache.org?

Comment: See this : http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html , Contributing to Jmeter. Creating a PR is explained

Comment: Eclipse Team → Create Patch should be  Team → Apply Patch?

Comment: Hi, no apply is when you want to take a provided patch file and apply it on your project. Create is when you want to create the patch for others to use it based on your current code.